# Postgres-equivalent of python any( i==x for i in j)

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a `jsonb` column in Postgres 11. Each element in this column looks like

```
[{"field1": "a", "field2": "b"}, {"field1": "c", "field2": "d"}, ...]
```

The number of elements in the top level jsonb list is not fixed, but the list is guaranteed to always contain at least 1 element. Each top level elemnt is guaranteed to have the same fields, so you don't have to check whether "field1" exists - it's guaranteed that it does.

I would like to answer the question, for each record, "does this json list have at least one element where field1 equals 'a'?"

In python this would be, if j is the json:

```
any( i["field1"] == "a" for i in j )
```

How do I do this in Postgres 11?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elemets()` in an `EXISTS` subquery that filters for the key `field1` to equal `'a'`.

```
SELECT c,
       EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.c) e
                                                     (e)
                      WHERE e.e->>'field1' = 'a') has_a
       FROM (VALUES ('[{"field1": "a", "field2": "b"}, {"field1": "c", "field2": "d"}]'::jsonb),
                    ('[{"field1": "e", "field2": "f"}, {"field1": "g", "field2": "h"}]'::jsonb)) AS t
                                                                                                    (c);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2f72a9065a62a91441b9ff926e59e30e)

And ideally, as the schema of the JSON array elements seem fixed and you don't only handle the JSON as an atom but want to query single pieces of it, you don't use JSON at all but good old relational means like an extra table storing the now JSON array elements.

Comment: Exactly right, thank you. What's that syntax though? After `FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.c)` the first `e` is the name of the column, but what is the second `e` inside parenthesis?

Comment: @yotere: No, the first one isn't the name name of the column. The first one is the alias of the *table* (as `jsonb_array_elements()` returns a set, not a scalar) the *second* one is the alias of the column. I actually forgot to fully qualify that column in the `WHERE` clause. I edited that to make things clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the alias of the column. But ok, now I understand it's the alias of the table, followed by the alias of the column in parenthesis, thank you.